In an $r$-player normal-form game, is the maximum regret function Lipschitz continuous under $L^{\infty}$ norm?
There are $r$ players.
Each player $i$ has an action space $A_i$ of size $n_i$.
The (mixed) strategy $x_i$ of player $i$ is a probability distribution over $A_i$.
$\Delta_{n_i}=\{x^i\in R^{n_i}:x^i \ge 0, \Sigma_{k=1}^{n_i}x_k^i=1\}$.
A strategy profile $x=(x^1,...,x^r) \in \Delta_{n_1} \times ... \times \Delta_{n_r}$ is a tuple of all players’ strategies.
Each player $i$ has a payoff function $u_i$ from $\Pi_{j=1}^{r} A^j$ to $[0,1]$.
and for strategy profile $x$, $u_i(x) = E_{a \sim x}[u_i(a)]$.
for $x^i \in \Delta_{n_i}, x^{-i} \in \Delta_{n_1} \times ... \times \Delta_{n_{i-1}} \times 
\Delta_{n_{i+1}} \times ... \times \Delta_{n_r}$
define the regret of player $i$ as $f_i(x):=max_{\underline{x^i} \in \Delta_{n_i}} u_i(\underline{x^i}, x^{-i}) - u_i({x^i}, x^{-i}) = max_{\underline{x^i} \in \Delta_{n_i}} u_i(\underline{x^i}, x^{-i}) - u_i(x) $
maximum regret function is defined as $f(x):=max_{i\in\{1,...,r\}} f_i(x)$.
is $f(x)$ Lipschitz continuous under $L^{\infty}$ norm?
I mean, is there a constant $C$ such that $\forall x\in \Delta_{n_1} \times ... \times \Delta_{n_r}, \forall y \in \Delta_{n_1} \times ... \times \Delta_{n_r}$,$ |f(x)-f(y)| \le C|| x - y ||_{L^{\infty}}$?
$f(x)$ has non-differentiable points and computationally challenging. Does anyone have a good method to determine whether it is Lipschitz continuous?

The core of the problem is whether the alteration of the strategy profile $x$ changes the regret maximum value. Regret distribution and the permissible range for player $i$ are given in the following equation:
$$f_i(x) = \max_{\underline{x^i} \in \Delta_{n_i}} u_i(\underline{x^i}, x^{-i}) - u_i(x)$$
The biggest possible regret is $f(x) = \max_{i} f_i(x)$.
We aim to prove that there is a certain constant $C$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq C\|x - y\|_\infty$, i.e., there are two strategy profiles $x$ and $y$. To attain it, let the player regret function $f_i(x)$ be primary. It contains the payoff that is multilinear in mixed strategies.
Player, the expected payoff function, is:
$$u_i(x)= \sum_{a \in A}u_i(a) \Pi_{j} x^j(a^j)$$
The main point is that the change in $f_i(x)$ is constrained by the alteration of the per-player payoff function, $u_i(x)$.
Find the solution to the equation $|u_i(x)-u_i(y)|$. As the $u_i$ are bounded between 0 and 1, solely by the systematic sophistication of the expansion of the product term in $u_i(x)$ and one of the basic axioms of the triangle inequality, we see that,
$$|u_i(x) - u_i(y)| \leq r n_{max}^r \|x - y\|_\infty$$
In fact, it can be established that the difference of the regret function, $|f_i(x)-f_i(y)|$, is, indeed, a bounded functional relation $2 r n_{max}^r \|x - y\|_\infty$. This is because the $f_i(x)$expression max also possesses the Lipschitz property thus, we have the faulty inequality $$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq 2 r n_{max}^r \|x - y\|_\infty$$
Therefore, it makes sense that the $f(x)$ is, in fact, Lipschitz continuous which is with the Lipschitz constant $C = 2 r n_{max}^r$, where $n_{max}$ is the maximal size of the action space for players, and $r$ is the number of players. This constraint is tight; however, this serves as a cover in showing Lipschitz continuity.
In the max operation, we see a component of non-differentiability in $f(x)$, which would not lead to a break in Lipschitz continuity. It provides a deductive understanding that, although there is non-differentiability, the whole regret function still relates a linear constraint to the changes in its value.
This gives the proof that the maximum regret function is Lipschitz continuous with respect to the infinity norm $L^\infty$.
